# Omron E3JK R4M2

Tags: sensor

I want to connect an E3JK sensor to my Siemens LOGO 24RC controller but don't know how to do it.

How many input pins on the controller do I need for one sensor?

Also I don't understand what power supply to use for this sensor.

This picture is from its manual.

What power source do I need? Can I use and 12 VDC and 24 VDC? Can I use any voltage in range of 12 to 240 VDC, and my sensor will work fine in any case?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per the datasheet observe the following:

The power source is (24-240 VAC) or (12-240 VDC) on brown/blue wires so it gives you flexibility. Good.

The type of output is contact output (relay output.) For your model (E3JK-R4M2) there will be a white, a black, and a gray wire which will send the signal to your Siemens LOGO.

If there is an obstacle (blocks the path of the Omron sensor) the white and black will be open circuit. Also, white and gray will be short circuit.

If there is no obstacle it will be the opposite.

How you connect it to your Siemens LOGO depends on how you program the controller.

[Datasheet for the E3JK from Omron.](https://www.ia.omron.com/data_pdf/cat/e3jk_e432-e1_8_2_csm1012459.pdf)

Comment: So, as I understand, if the power supply is 240 VAC my sensor will send 24 VAC signal to the controller and 12 VDC if the power supply is 240 VDC. Does I understand correct?

Comment: No, not really, the power supply circuit is isolated from the control circuit. The signal that the controller monitors (in case of the obstacle ) will be the same signal which it sends from the controller digital output.

Comment: Thanks! Useally I saw the power supply characteristic like 24(+/- 10%), for example. It looks very strange for me that  a sensor can work with 24, or 29, or 57, ior even with 134 V normally. Why so big range? It was my problem.