# Omron E3JK R4M1

Tags: sensor

I have a sensor E3JK R4M1. I dont know how to connect it to power supply and to my controller. I have not its manual. In the Internet I find manual for Omron E3JK R4M1. This is a pic from this manual
[image]

But on the case of my sensor there is this pic 
[image]

It is noy original Omron E3JK R4M1 for sure.

How I must connect this sensor?

Blue and brown will be power supply and white gray black will send signals to my controller? But in this case I dont understand how a sensor which is supplied by 24VDC is able send 240 VAC to controller.

Comment: What do you mean by "the controller" when you say this device will "send 240 VAC to controller"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Omron E3JK R4M2](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/442676/omron-e3jk-r4m2)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. My that question was about the original Omron sensor. This question is about an alternative product

Answer (score 2):

> But in this case I dont understand how a sensor which is supplied by 24VDC is able send 240 VAC to controller.

It doesn't.

It just closes or opens the contacts as shown.

If you connect 240 VAC to White, then 240 VAC will appear at either the black or grey terminal, depending on whether the sensor detects an optical signal.

If you connect some other voltage to white, then that other voltage will appear at the black or grey terminal (again, depending whether the sensor detects an optical signal).

The "3A 250 VAC" marking indicates a maximum rating. You should not connect more than 250 VAC to any of the output terminals, and you should not connect a load that draws more than 3 A, for whatever your applied voltage is.